# Ios static library of an entire application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, static-libraries

Is it possible to create an iOS static library that contains an entire iOS application code with all storyboards and with all frameworks?

I know that is possible to create a static library and use bundle resource that contains storyboards. I tested it and it works.

My question is if static library can contain external frameworks. Is it possible?

Do you have an example about it to share with me?

Comment: You mean like CocoaPods is doing with static pods?

Comment: yes, exactly. I have created a Framework instead a static library and it works.